# Trying to display multiple projectiles on screen

Tags: python, pygame

Essentially, I am trying to display multiple projectiles on the screen for the player to avoid.

At this point, I'm not worried about hit boxes or anything like that, just simply trying to get multiple projectiles to display. It displays one, then the projectile disappears off the screen and never shows back up.

I believe this may be a scope issue, but I'm not entirely sure. I have moved around pretty much every  piece of code I can think of to no avail.

```
class Game:

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def __init__(self): 
        self.enemy = Projectile() 
        self.enemies = []

    def loop(self):
        self.clock.tick(30) 

        for enemy in self.enemies:
            if self.enemy.y < 925 and self.enemy.x < self.screen_width: 
                self.enemy.x += self.enemy.velocity
                self.enemy.frame_count += 1
            else:
                self.enemies.pop(self.enemies.index(self.enemy))

        if len(self.enemies) < 5:
            self.enemies.append(self.enemy)

    def render(self):
        # other stuff

        for enemy in self.enemies: 
            self.enemy.draw_projectile(self._display_surf)
```

And then in my projectile file I have:

```
class Projectile():
     # projectile images

    def __init__(self):
     # stuff 

    def draw(self, gameDisplay): 

        if self.frame_count > 118: 
            self.frame_count = 0 

        display_window.blit(self.projectile_sprites[self.frame_count],(self.x, self.y))
```

I'm trying to get multiple projectile-type enemies on the screen. I looked over a few tutorials on how to do this type of thing and I can't get the expected results.

Comment: In the projectile class, it actually says: gameDisplay.blit(self.projectile_sprites[self.frame_count], (self.x, self.y))

Comment: I do not see where you are creating the projectiles. Ideally you shoud have a projectile instance of each projectile you want to draw

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing with self.enemies.append(self.enemy) where self.enemy is the instance of the class.

Comment: I did a few print statements to check out the x and y positions and the enemy gets stuck at the end of the screen and never pops out of the list. Also, the list only ever has one instance of the class in it. I tried moving the instance of the class down to my loop but they just keep appearing before getting popped out of the list.

Comment: You are just copying references of the same object. You should call each time `Projectile()`. Should be something like `self.enemies.append(Projectile())`.

Comment: I tried that but I got back the error: "Game object has no attribute enemy"

Comment: I've seen other stuffs, let me write them in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things need to be fixed. Not sure these fixs will be enough, but at least they will help.

Class `Projectile` seems ok sintactically. I cannot speak for the omitted parts, though.
However, you never use the `gameDisplay` argument in the `draw` function, but you have a `display_window`. Are they supposed to be the same thing? If so, use the same name.
I guess `display_window` / `gameDisplay` is the display, the surface initialized with `pygame.display.set_mode()`. If so, is fine.

For the `Game` class, see the comments I added.

```
class Game:

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def __init__(self): 
        #self.enemy = Projectile() remove this line, is useless.
        self.enemies = []

    def loop(self):
        self.clock.tick(30) 

        for enemy in self.enemies:
            if enemy.y < 925 and enemy.x < self.screen_width:
                #no need of self before enemy in this section. Otherwise you
                #do not refer to the "enemy" on which you are looping but to
                #the attribute "enemy" (which I removed). They are different things. 
                enemy.x += enemy.velocity
                enemy.frame_count += 1
            else:
                self.enemies.pop(self.enemies.index(enemy))
                #I leave this here for now, but remember that editing
                #a list on which you are looping is a bad idea in general.

        if len(self.enemies) < 5:
            self.enemies.append(Projectile())
            #each iteration you need to create a new instance of the class.

    def render(self):
        # other stuff

        for enemy in self.enemies: 
            enemy.draw(self._display_surf)
            #again, no self before enemy, same reason of before.
```

I do not know what is `draw_projectile()`. I suppose you meant to use the `draw()` method of `Projectile` class, it makes sense thos way.
Again `self._display_surf` is not defined in your code, I supposed is the display which you pass to the `draw()` function.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to thank you! I got so caught up with writing self before pretty much everything that I didnt consider that it wasn't relevant in that for loop. I'm pretty new to OOP, and this helped a bunch in my understanding as well as solving the problem I've been struggling with for hours. Thank you!